# Creating SQL Server database from vb.net, without SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sqlcmd

I'm programming an installer for an application in VB.net. My application needs a SQL Server database to work, but I want that my app runs in machines without SQL Server instances installed.

Exists `sqlcmd` standalone or something? (I would like to include it in my installation pack)

Is possible create a database via `sqlcmd` this way?

Thank you

Comment: You should look at LocalDB bits. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx

Comment: Try using SQLite or SQL CE. For latter there is a bit of work adding correct .dlls, but it can be done.

Comment: If your application **uses** a SQL Server `.mdf` database file, then **you MUST** install a server-based SQL Server version on that machine (or that machine has to have access to a SQL Server instace on the network it's connected to). You ***CANNOT*** use or create a SQL Server `.mdf` database file ***WITHOUT*** having SQL Server installed

Comment: thanks, it's what I thought ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the full power of the SQL Server Database you need to install an instance of SQL Server. If the problem is the cost for the final user, and they meet the criteria, they can install SQL Server Express, that is free.

But, if your application:

- Only uses the database to persist information locally and you don’t
  need to share this information with other instances of the
  application running on other PCs.
- Uses .NET 4.02 or newer.

You can use [SQL Server Express LocalDB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh510202(v=sql.120).aspx), available on SQL Server 2012 or later.

LocalDB lets you use MDF files and work like you were using a full SQL Server database, with some limitations, without the need of installing and configuring a full SQL Server instance.

Your installation program can launch the installation of SQL Server Express LocalDB (SqlLocalDB.msi), so the user don’t have to install the product separately.